# How do I move my Firebase directory in my Google Cloud Shell/Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-shell

some time ago I set up Firebase Functions & Hosting (never used the Hosting but extensively using Functions) to work with my Android App that I'm building. When I set this up, I didn't know very much about the environment and didn't realize "where" I was creating the directories. I ended up creating the directory under `/home/myusername/firebase`. While I still don't know much more (lol) about the environment, I came to realize that other users in the project are unable to see these directories, because they are in my home/user directory. (right?) I now have another user in the project, that needs to be able to access these directories.

I know that I can probably "easily" just move these directories with the mv command, but is that the correct/proper way? I assume it is not.

How do I go about safely moving these directories to a higher level directory --- OR: How do I go about putting these directories in a place where other users can access them, as well?

Thank you for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are overthinking things.  Just move files around with `mv` like you would normally.  Cloud Shell doesn't really operate much differently than your desktop with respect to moving files and directories around.

If you want to share your source code, you should use some form of source control, such as GitHub or Google Cloud Source Repositories.  Cloud Shell is not a good place to share data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are obviously right.I did a lot of homework here and realized that I profoundly misunderstood the way this works.  It really doesn't matter *where* the source files are, as long as they are being properly deployed to the right projects, etc. Months ago  I just followed a tutorial on setting up some cloud functions for my project (android app) and just *coded* without touching anything surrounding it in fear of breaking something. (lol). Now I'm actually setting everything up locally with vsCode and transitioning away from having my source files in my cloud shell.